# How to retrieve class property type dynamically?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a class that should keep some values defined by exact types. Here's simplified view of my class:

```
interface SomeType1 {
  id1: string;
  data1: object;
}

interface SomeType2 {
  id2: string;
  data2: object;
}

export enum Databases {
  db1 = 'db1',
  db2 = 'db2',
}

interface Tables {
  [Databases.db1]: SomeType1;
  [Databases.db2]: SomeType2;
}

class MyClass {
  tables: Tables;

  constructor(tables: Tables) {
    // simplified to not oveload with code
    this.tables = tables;
  }
}

const MyInstance = new MyClass();

export default MyInstance;
```

And here's how I'd like to use it

```
import MyInstance, { Databases } from './db';

export const useDB = (table: Databases) => {
  const currentTable = MyInstance.tables[table];
  // simplified to not oveload with code
  return currentTable;
};
```

What I am trying to achieve is exact type that is returned in `useDB` function depending on provided value (`Databases.db1`, `Databases.db2`) but I get computed type `SomeType1 | SomeType2` which is doesn't satisfy my needs. Is there any way to get exact type using generics? I am struggling to figure this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty straightforward usage of generics. Capture the type of your input variable as a generic so that typescript can use it to infer the correct return type when you call your function.

For example:

```
export const useDB = <DB extends Databases>(table: DB) => {
  const currentTable = MyInstance.tables[table];
  // simplified to not oveload with code
  return currentTable;
};

const db1 = useDB(Databases.db1); // has type: SomeType1
const db2 = useDB(Databases.db2); // has type: SomeType2
```

---

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAlgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYAIDKB7AtjAFQE8AHGARnQG9R10wATcgLnQGco5IBzAblvQMkUJC3TYARgCsYKKPxABfUKEixEqDDnzEyAJmoDGe1hy4Q+AoSJPjps+aGUhQMAB4lscKOhgQArrjoACLCSBJIbDBshiB0DBKUALzoAOQJ5KkANFYSBinpedlOKuDQ8Mho6AThADbRsXQA2qEiEVFsAHQZALqs2oSkFArNreGR0d15fVh4g-oKzqAotZExALJEAMKrbDE0ceht9WysNRInCgIo2BBm-nJeABTH0Wd10QCUjXToAPR-dhgXAkWpgBBgGAMI7YdAQbA+bAANxgtWwSGhAHcwFAABboG4MGACOh4sBdV4xFKUkboZxLEA3O4+TYASWZSAgVRSEBgmPQmx2ayeVEU6Ei4ogRE+VxA7k83gJtw46H8UWCACF0CkADya3xuWAQBgxMbtaIAPheH1Ymu+SQtPyZKpQ-jgcD8UHO9W1AqI7I4nLQnUpTVePVpAKBILBEKhMLhCPEKLRGPQ2LxSqJAg9UDdEAJbo90G9MEWsudPgyvrVME1TzNEy6GRl-0BA10FGWyqreRr6o1DbC5ubeVbUY7Qz0pSAA)